# Can tweet an image using Tweepy, but can't tweet a video

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm testing out tweeting using the Tweepy API today. It all seems very easy to use so far, but I've come across a very confusing error. I have successfully tweeted an image, but changing the input from a jpeg to an mp4 file throws up an error. Now according to the guides I've read, this should work fine... so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've put the code I use, and the error, below. Help appreciated.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

media = api.media_upload("test.mp4")
tweet = "Test works!"
post_result = api.update_status(status=tweet, media_ids=[media.media_id])
```

---

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video.py", line 16, in <module>
    media = api.media_upload("test.mp4")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 231, in media_upload
    file_type=file_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1392, in _pack_image
    raise TweepError('Could not determine file type')
tweepy.error.TweepError: Could not determine file type
```

Comment: Is video even implemented in Tweepy? According to [this page](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1414) it's in development but not merged into the main branch.

Answer (score 2):

Docs says that `media_upload` is used to upload images.

> API.media_upload(filename[, file])
>
> Use this endpoint to upload images to Twitter.

http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=media_upload#API.media_upload

Looking through their docs, it doesn't seem that they support video upload.

Docs: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Please add a citation of doc you have found to complete your answer.

Comment: Thank you @AlexK., added direct link and a quote.